# Copy/paste program that automatically renames duplicate files of different sizes

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm looking for a program that can copy/paste large number of files quickly for Windows 7. If it finds a file in the source folder that shares the name of a file in the destination folder, it should have options for automatically handling such conflicts. For example, I can tell it to compare the file sizes, and if the sizes are the same, skip copying the file from the source folder; otherwise, rename the file from the source folder and copy it to the destination folder. I've tried several different programs so far, including WinMerge, FastCopy, and SuperCopier, but they either overwrite without asking, give you the same endless conflict error windows that Windows already offers, or just plain lacks anything like the features I'm looking for. Does such a program exist?

Comment: (Teracopy doesn't have this feature either.)

Comment: Should it compare the content of files with identical name and size?

Comment: Why not just select the "Yes but keep both files option" when copying in Windows.  There is also a checkbox that allows you to specify the same should be done for all files in the action.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul No need to check the contents. Basically, due to my previous lack of organizational ability, I have folders scattered around my computer full of photos I've taken. Some of these photos are resized duplicates that I have for uploading to photo sites, but the names are still the same. Rather than just assuming all photos with the same name are completely identical, or sifting through each photo to see what its dimensions or file size is, I'd like something to compare them and rename as necessary.

Comment: @James No, Windows only cares about conflicts with the name. So let's say I move 300 photos into another folder, and Windows reports they're all in conflict; if I say to keep both versions for all, I now have 300 photos with 300 duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Copywhiz - http://www.conceptworld.com/Copywhiz . I think it would meet your requirements.

[image: Skip Identical Files]

[image: Rename Duplicate Files]

Description from the website:

> When copying files, Copywhiz can rename duplicate files so that you
>   can keep both versions of the file (the original file & the file being
>   copied).
>
> When the first duplicate file is detected, Copywhiz will ask you if
>   you wish to replace it. You can opt to rename the destination file
>   with a suffix instead of overwriting it. Or you may also rename the
>   file that is being copied.
>
> You can copy only newer or modified files by skipping identical files.
>   This will make the copy process much quicker. It is useful if you are
>   backing up your files to the same destination. Only new & changed
>   files are copied.
>
> Also, to ensure that the destination file is not replaced with an
>   older version of the file you can skip files that are identical/newer
>   in the destination folder.
>
> Eg. When maintaining a set of music files on yet another drive (USB
>   pen drive, music player etc), you can select these options to update
>   the collection with only newer or updated files saving you several
>   minutes each time.

You can choose 'Do it for all files" to automatically rename the files.